# How to jump to a specific line of code

Tags: ruby

I am pretty new to Ruby so please give me any advice you can offer. Thank you. 
Today I am almost finished on a simple in which at the end I ask the user if they would like to play again. I know how to do the If Else statement and everything like that but not how to jump back to the line of code where the game starts. I have done some research and found something called goto but found that it shouldn't be used. Is there anyway I can go to a specific line of code without messing everything up?
Thanks for all your help.

The example is:

```
print "Would you like to play again?"
puts "Yes or no"
again = gets.chomp!
again.capitalize!

if again == "Yes"
(Code to send back to line 9)
end
```

Comment: Ruby doesn't really have a `goto` statement, and you really don't want one, it instantly makes your code unmaintainable. Can you give a specific example of what you're trying to do so the Ruby way of approaching the problem can be explained?

Comment: Most games are structured around the concept of an [*event loop*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) where actions initiated by the user or by various in-game timers are handled. Each event is handled individually, usually in order, where an event might be a button push or a mouse movement. There's no need to go back to any particular line of code because when the handler finishes it just loops back and does something else by design.

Comment: Try putting your code in a `loop do .... end` loop. That will continue looping until a `break` or `break x` (`x` being a return value) is encountered. Some use `while(true) ... end`, but I most prefer `loop do`.  See [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) for details, including a simple example.

Comment: [Methods](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/writing_methods.html) are the way to seperate code into named, callable chunks. You "go to" the code by referencing the name of the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gist of this is using the `loop` approach where you can repeat something until you get a satisfactory answer:

```
def play_again?
  loop do
    print "Would you like to play again? Y/N"
    again = gets.chomp.capitalize

    case (again)
    when 'N'
      return false
    when 'Y'
      return true
    else
      puts "Huh? I don't know what that means."
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can incorporate this into your main program:

```
begin
  run_game
end while play_again?
```

That will keep running the game until `play_again?` returns `false`, which happens only if you type "N".

Comment: Thank you for your help tadman only when it runs it says run_game is an undefined variable. What should I set it to if anything? Thank you for your response.

Comment: That's a stub where you can put in whatever your game does. You can call it anything you like, or you can just put your game code right there. Putting it inside a method makes the overall structure of your program more apparent, though.

Comment: Thank you so much tadman. It is working fine now. Thank you for your help.